# Postfix: How to reject emails from all senders except one

Tags: postfix

I want to **reject** any emails that don't come from user@example.com. So far I've tried adding this to /etc/postfix/header_checks:

```
!/(^From:user@example.com)/ REJECT
```

And I added these lines to main.cf:

```
postconf -e header_checks=regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
postconf -e header_checks=pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

This configuration doesn't work, I can longer send any emails. When I do I get the following warning:

```
postfix/cleanup[194]: 4C8EB7200C3: reject: header Received: from [127.0.1.1] (unknown [172.28.0.1])??by example.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 4C8EB7200C3??for <incoming@example.com>; Tue,  4 Oct 2022 02:07:37 +0000 (UTC) from unknown[172.28.0.1]; from=<User@example.com> to=<incoming@example.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<[127.0.1.1]>: 5.7.1 message content rejected
```

I'm unsure what else to try. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Just to be sure: you do realize that pcre (Perl Compatible Regular Expression) and regexp (POSIX regular expression) are somewhat similar, but non-identical lookups?

Answer (score 1):

**Header checks are applied to *each* message header.** Thus, rejecting any message containing a header except the one you checked for.. rejects *all* valid messages. In your example it was rejected based on an unrelated but generally present header (`Received:`).

To fix your immediate problem, match only the header you actually care for:

```
# first skip over headers which match the expected value
/^Header: addr@example$/        DUNNO
/^Header: .* <addr@example>$/   DUNNO

# then reject messages containing that header with a value that was not skipped
/^Header:/                      REJECT 5.7.1 meaningful explanation of policy
```

However, this may still not fully address your problem.
For one, head address fields are impossible to correctly parse with just regex, at least not if you want to be able to deal with headers like `From: Joe(vacation until 2020-10-12) <joe@example.com>, Antony <anton@example.com>`.

But more crucially, such headers might be filled incorrectly, in error or with malicious intent. You probably want to instead filter based on something your server has actually checked against an acceptable policy, e.g. match the `Authentication-Results: myserver.example; example text` header - or diregard headers altogether, and instead directly match the rfc5321.MailFrom ("envelope sender") address using the `check_sender_access` in postfix, if that is more closely matching what you want to allow or reject.